Unusual Behaviour in 'joi' validation
I was working on a personal project and I wanted to use 'joi' library for validation of my request body.
import * as Joi from 'joi';

const joiSchema= Joi.object({
    ans: Joi.number().required().not(0),
}).unknown(true).keys();

const data = {
    ans: 0,
};

async function validateData() {
    try {
        const value =  await joiSchema.validateAsync(data);
        console.log('Validation succeeded:', value);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Validation error:', err);
    }
}

// Call the async function
validateData();

I have validation succeeded for ans:0 in this case but i have clearly mentioned that ans should not be zero , and infact the function validateData() gives validation succeeded even when i am passing string to it.
But when i remove keys() method from joiSchema I am getting the desired results.
I looked at the documentation also for keys() but could not find any satisfactory answers.

const joiSchema = Joi.object({
      ans: Joi.number().required().not(0),
    });

try to remove unknown() and keys()

Hi , yes when i remove keys() , it works fine but i wanted to know the reason behind it.

we use .keys() to explicitly add keys, but in this case u don't need any keys. the only key u need is 'ans', which is already specified.

But what if in future i want to extend this schema and add more keys, and how does it matter that adding .keys() interfere with my current logic of ans.

Because keys() function doesn't do what you think it does. From the docs: "Sets or extends the allowed object keys where:"
https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.13.3#objectkeysschema
